# How to use proxy with Auth in socket (python) (make reflector )

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to use http proxy in the socket.socket() python library. My PC connect >> 1.1.1.1:8080 >> mywebserver:8080

I found something from another question that works in c#: [How to use Proxy with TcpClient.ConnectAsync()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066981/how-to-use-proxy-with-tcpclient-connectasync)

what am trying to do here is achieve belove code in python

```
 TcpClient _client;

    NetworkStream _stream;

    public TcpClient ProxyTcpClient(string targetHost, int targetPort, string httpProxyHost, int httpProxyPort, string proxyUserName, string proxyPassword)
    {
            const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            Uri proxyUri = new UriBuilder
            {
                Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp,
                Host = httpProxyHost,
                Port = httpProxyPort
            }.Uri;
            Uri targetUri = new UriBuilder
            {
                 Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp,
                 Host = targetHost,
                 Port = targetPort
            }.Uri;

        WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy(proxyUri, true);
        webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUserName, proxyPassword);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(targetUri);
        request.Proxy = webProxy;
        request.Method = "CONNECT";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        Type responseType = responseStream.GetType();
        PropertyInfo connectionProperty = responseType.GetProperty("Connection", Flags);
        var connection = connectionProperty.GetValue(responseStream, null);
        Type connectionType = connection.GetType();
        PropertyInfo networkStreamProperty = connectionType.GetProperty("NetworkStream", Flags);
        NetworkStream networkStream = (NetworkStream)networkStreamProperty.GetValue(connection, null);
        Type nsType = networkStream.GetType();
        PropertyInfo socketProperty = nsType.GetProperty("Socket", Flags);
        Socket socket = (Socket)socketProperty.GetValue(networkStream, null);

        return new TcpClient { Client = socket };
    }
```

this old post answer not working [Establishing a TCP connection through an authenticated HTTP proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480141/establishing-a-tcp-connection-through-an-authenticated-http-proxy)

ps: am reposting this question please check and try code yourself before closing it thankyou :)

Comment: *"this old post answer not working"* - this is not a useful error description. And it is not helpful to repost your closed question with only this "does not work" detail added.  Show instead what you actually did, show what you expected to happen and show what happened instead - in full detail.

Comment: the point here is if you read it carefully what I ask here is to help me rewrite the c# code in python so before closing it you should reread it anyway sir thankyou for the help :)

@SteffenUllrich

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. It is a place to help you tackle the problem - which is not the same as fully solve the problem to you. It is expected that you do invest your own efforts, not simply try to outsource your problem . I've therefore pointed you to a similar question which has code which is supposed to solve your problem. Your only reaction was that the code does not work, without any kind of details what exactly you tried and what exactly is not working. This makes it impossible to help you get this code working.