# How to send username:password to unittest's app.get() request?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, basic-authentication, flask-restful

This is part of my unit test in Flask-RESTful.

```
self.app = application.app.test_client()
rv = self.app.get('api/v1.0/{0}'.format(ios_sync_timestamp))
eq_(rv.status_code,200)
```

Within the command line I could use curl to send the username:password to the service:

```
curl -d username:password http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/1234567
```

How do I achieve the same within my unit test's get() ?

Since my get/put/post require authentication otherwise the test would fail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [RFC 1945, Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945)

> [11.1  Basic Authentication Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11.1)
>
> ...
>
> To receive authorization, the client sends the user-ID and password,
> separated by a single colon (":") character, within a base64 [5]
> encoded string in the credentials.string.
>
> ...
>
> If the user agent wishes to send the user-ID "Aladdin" and password
> open sesame", it would use the following header field:
>
> ```
>   Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
> ```

So if you really use http basic authentication you can solution like below, although your `curl` usage suggests some other authentication scheme.

```
from base64 import b64encode

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + b64encode("{0}:{1}".format(username, password)).decode('utf-8')
}

rv = self.app.get('api/v1.0/{0}'.format(ios_sync_timestamp), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution - All credit goes to Doug Black

```
def request(self, method, url, auth=None, **kwargs):
    headers = kwargs.get('headers', {})
    if auth:
        headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(auth[0] + ':' + auth[1])

    kwargs['headers'] = headers

    return self.app.open(url, method=method, **kwargs)
```

and then use this method in your tests:

```
resp = self.request('GET', 'api/v1.0/{0}'.format(ios_sync_timestamp), auth=(username, password))
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3, try the following example:

```
from base64 import b64encode
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % b64encode(b"username:password").decode("ascii")
}

self.app.get("foo/", headers=headers)
```

If you'd like to use dynamic variables for username and password, then try something like:

```
'Basic %s' % b64encode(bytes(username + ':' + password, "utf-8")).decode("ascii")
```

See also: [Python, HTTPS GET with basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999565/python-https-get-with-basic-authentication)