# arangodb verify _users password

Tags: python, arangodb

How can I verify if a given password matches with password from collection `_users` in arangoDB?

I know it can be done with Foxx app and arangosh but I am not using them as I am using my own API in python. So I don't know how to access to the password and check if matches with the given password without using Foxx or arangosh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on the system `_users` collection for your own user logic. The collection is strictly intended for ArangoDB's own user objects, not for application-level user management.

If you really do want to use ArangoDB's own user management, the best way to expose that when authentication is disabled is to use the `org/arangodb/users` module inside ArangoDB (e.g. using Foxx). The module provides an `isValid` method that takes a username and password and returns a boolean indicating whether the combination is valid or not:

```
var users = require('org/arangodb/users');
controller.post('/checkpw', function (req, res) {
  var credentials = req.params('credentials');
  res.json({
    valid: users.isValid(
      credentials.username,
      credentials.password
    )
  });
})
.bodyParam('credentials', joi.object({
  username: joi.string().required(),
  password: joi.string().required()
}).required());
```

The users HTTP API currently doesn't expose this method, so this is the only way to do it without relying on extremely unstable implementation details (the format of the `_users` collection has changed throughout 2.x and the collection may change again in the future).

EDIT: ArangoDB 3.0 will likely add an API route that returns a token (rather than cluttering up the database with session objects) when supplied with a valid username and password. This should make it easier to integrate with the built-in user management but the caveats remain the same: ArangoDB users are primarily intended for API-level authorization, not for application logic.

Comment: Thank you. Then I guess that the best option will be create my own users collection

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way is to simply try a flat http request, and check for its result. The most simple call is `_api/version`; We prefix the database to find out whether the user is allowed to access a specific database. For this example we use `_system`; you need to replace it with the database you want to test the authentication against.

```
curl --dump - http://Joe:passvoid@localhost:8529/_db/_system/_api/version
GET /_db/_system/_api/version HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic Sm9lOnBhc3N2b2lk
User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
Host: localhost:8529
Accept: */*


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ArangoDB
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 37

{"server":"arango","version":"2.8.8"}

curl --dump - http://Joe:WRONGpassvoid@localhost:8529/_db/_system/_api/version 
GET /_db/_system/_api/version HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic Sm9lOldST05HcGFzc3ZvaWQ=
User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
Host: localhost:8529
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: ArangoDB
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Www-Authenticate: basic realm="arangodb/_system"
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
```

So you need to check for the HTTP status code: `200` -> Success; `401` -> fail. See [howto create authentication headers with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999565/python-https-get-with-basic-authentication) for details of the python specific http handling.

Comment: The thing is that i do not have activated arangodb authentication  so I can access with both wrong or correct password `You are about to log in to the site "localhost" with the username "Joe", but the website does not require authentication [...]`. I don't want to activate authentication because users do not directly access to the database but through an app so I just want to take advantage that arangodb comes with `_users` collection and use it. If its not possible getting the password from `_users` maybe I should create my own user collection? (but this is what I was trying to avoid)