# How open a password protected image url with python?

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, urllib

I have an Image URL that it's protected with a username and a password. Whenever I try to access the URL with a username and password in Python modules `requests` and `urlib2` module its gives `HTTP error', 401, 'Unauthorized' ,if I tried this URL in web browser it will ask the credentials in javascript prompt box , can anyone please help me to download the image from the URL with username and password. thanks in advance

Image URL is [here.](http://playground.nexleaf.org:8080/ODKAggregate/view/binaryData?blobKey=st_notes_20160817%5B%40version%3Dnull%20and%20%40uiVersion%3Dnull%5D%2Fnotes_survey_test%5B%40key%3Duuid%3Af44b31c8-2550-4dfb-b791-0dcc83eff5f2%5D%2Fst_notes_image)

Comment: you could use the `scrapy` library (http://scrapy.org/)

Comment: Please post the image url?
Is that in your same project  or some external urL?

Comment: Thank you, but i need to use this in my django project

Comment: Can do much help without the url itself.

Comment: @Jithin , yes its external url

Comment: "Javascript prompt"? I think it's the standard *HTTP Basic Auth* prompt, not much to do with Javascript at all.

Comment: do you have any sample code..

Comment: Send the authentication parameters with the request. take a look at this: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication

Comment: Specifically, look here for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37336908/476