# pycurl: How to authenticate making a POST request

Tags: python-2.7, curl, post, urlencode, pycurl

Using the following command via cURL (Windows): `curl -u username:password "https://website.com/update/" --data "simChangesList=%5B%7B%22simId%22%3A760590802%2C%22changeType%22%3A2%2C%22targetValue%22%3A%22000307%22%2C%22effectiveDate%22%3Anull%7D%5D" --compressed`
 I am able to successfully post my data authenticated as per the `-u` switch.

How can I successfully create the same POST request using pycurl?

```
import urllib
import pycurl

enc = urllib.quote('simChangesList:[{"simId":760590802,"changeType":2,"targetValue":000307,"effectiveDate":null}]')
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://website.com/update/')

c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, enc)
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)

c.perform()
c.close()
```

Executing the above code will not POST the data I am wanting it to do, and I suspect it's because I'm requiring authentication, as per the Windows cURL version.

How can I successfully modify my code so that I can POST my data authenticated?

Comment: See [setting options](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html#setting-options) and [`CURLOPT_USERPWD`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERPWD.html). But if you're going to be making a lot of web requests with python, I'd highly suggest checking out the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6999774/4909087

Comment: @Coldspeed I'm using v2.7, not 3.

Comment: It will work for 2.7 as well.