# Set Proxy with Credentials in Python's http client

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.7's Http Client to make an https request, which uses a corporate proxy with credentials. I'm getting `socket.gai`  error. pls help me with on how to use proxy with credentials for http.client, also let me know If the below error mentioned is due to proxy or not

```
import http.client

getApi = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.example.com")
getApi.set_tunnel(host,port)
getApi.request("GET", "/")
resp = getApi.getresponse()
print(resp.status)
```

The error I get

> File "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 748, in
>   getaddrinfo
>       for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: Seems problem in your host-name. Is hostname resolving to right server?

Comment: yeah, the hostname is correct, but it needs credentials to pass through, how do I pass the credentials using http client?

Comment: In which format credentials to be sent, like basic auth or in plain text or a cert? Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999565/python-https-get-with-basic-authentication. Let me know if any more info is required.