# Authentication credentials with Rest API

Tags: python, powershell, rest

I am trying to retrive information, that is accessible via Rest API. But I am not sure how to pass authentication credentials.

GET endpoint doesn't have any place to insert username and password.

When I try to get this info through browser it asks for credentials.
But how can I call GET request with python and pass credentials that are required to log in into server?

[Here is how it looks via browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itJrR.png)

@EDIT
Ok here is what I found:

It works with powershell:

```
$root = 'http://<server>:8080/local/people-counter/.api?live-sum.json'
$user = "user"
$pass= "pass"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $secpasswd)

$result = Invoke-RestMethod $root -Credential $credential
$result
```

This gives me a proper response:

```
serial    : <string>
name      : <string>
timestamp : 20210422114954
in        : 6
out       : 6
```

But how do I translate this to python?
I already tried:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
response = requests.get('http://<server>:8080/local/people-counter/.api?live-sum.json', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))

print(response)
```

But response is always:

```
<Response [401]>
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, HTTPS GET with basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999565/python-https-get-with-basic-authentication)

Comment: Most likely it's using HTTPBasic Auth. Depending how you are trying to connect will depend on how you can set the headers

Comment: Alright, I learnt more about HTTPBasic Auth but it doesn't work in my case.
Here is my code:
`import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
response = requests.get('http://<server ip>:8080/local/people-counter/.api?live-sum.json', auth=('user', 'password'))

print(response)`
But it returns 401, which is wierd because when I use the same credentials via browser it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTTP Client`.

Her's more: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main() async {
  var client = http.Client();
  String username = 'example';
  String password = 'example123';
  String basicAuth =
      'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
  String url =
    'https://example.com/api';

  print(basicAuth);

  var response = await client.get(contacts_url,
      headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
  print(response.statusCode);
  developer.log(response.body);
}
```