# How to use Python to retrieve xml page that requires http login?

Tags: python, xml, iis, authentication, urllib

When I access a page on an IIS server to retrieve xml, using a query parameter through the browser (using the http in the below example) I get a pop-up login dialog for username and password (appears to be a system standard dialog/form). and once submitted the data arrives. as an xml page.

How do I handle this with urllib? when I do the following, I never get prompted for a uid/psw.. I just get a traceback indicating the server (correctly ) id's me as not authorized. Using python 2.7 in Ipython notebook

```
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.nalmls.com/SERetsHuntsville/Search.aspx?SearchType=Property&Class=RES&StandardNames=0&Format=COMPACT&Query=(DATE_MODIFIED=2012-09-28T00:00:00%2B)&Limit=10")
s = f.read()
f.close()
```

Pointers to doc also appreciated! did not find this exact use case.

I plan to parse the xml to csv if that makes a difference.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4188709/416467) to a similar question looks pretty straightforward.

Comment: That does not work... Dunno why, get a 401 not authorized...

Comment: That answer is using Http Basic Authentication, the url you are using needs Digest Authentication.

Comment: Yes, see below! Digest auth was the trick! Should be noted that that is the probable default for MS servers....

Comment: as I don't have access to the server I don't have a chance to test, but I think using http://username:password@website.com/user/... as url should also work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are dealing with [http authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). I've always found it tricky to get working quickly with the urllib library. The [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) python package makes it super simple.

```py
url = "http://www.nalmls.com/SERetsHuntsville/Search.aspx?SearchType=Property&Class=RES&StandardNames=0&Format=COMPACT&Query=(DATE_MODIFIED=2012-09-28T00:00:00%2B)&Limit=10"
r = requests.get(url, auth=('user', 'pass'))
page = r.text
```

If you look at the headers for that url you can see that it is using digest authentication:

> {'content-length': '1893', 'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',
>   'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319', 'server': 'Microsoft-IIS/7.5',
>   'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Fri, 05 Oct 2012 18:20:54 GMT',
>   'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'www-authenticate':
>   **'Digest realm=**"Solid Earth", nonce="MTAvNS8yMDEyIDE6MjE6MjUgUE0",
>   opaque="0000000000000000", stale=false, algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"'}

So you will need:

```py
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

Comment: Looked good but did not work, still getting un-authorized...MMMM sure looks like it should work though!

Comment: You might need requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass')) by default requests does HTTPBasicAuth

Comment: My response from the server is `The MIME type of the request is invalid`. How would we change the request type to `text/xml`?

Comment: You can set it with the headers kwarg: `requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass'), headers={'Content-Type': 'text/xml'})`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it but i suggest you start with [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) and it's batteries included.

```
import urllib2, base64

req = urllib2.Request("http://webpage.com//user")
b64str = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % b64str)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

You can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/),[mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) or [selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) if your task gets harder. Googling will give you enough examples for each one of these,

Comment: you could use `base64.b64encode()` to avoid unnecessary `.replace('\n','')`.

Comment: This is the answer referred to in the 1st comment from kindall, don't know why but I still got a 401 not authorized...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a couple of ways:

1. Use `urllib`/`urllib2` and `requests` as others have suggested
2. Use [`Mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to simulate manual form-filling and get back the response