# How could I use python-request to grab a linkedin page?

Tags: python, linkedin-api, python-requests

I use below code try to grab a linked in page,but it seems this method couldn't let me login,just show me the unauthorized home page.

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


payload = {
'session-key': 'my account',
'session-password': 'my password'
}

URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login'
s = requests.session()
s.post(URL, data=payload)

r = s.get('http://www.linkedin.com/nhome')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print(soup)
```

`

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751293/how-to-use-python-to-retrieve-xml-page-that-requires-http-login

Comment: @m170897017  that not suitable for linkedin case,could you have a try then give me right code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *much* more complicated than what you've got so far.

You will need to do something like:

- Load https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login
- Parse the response with `BeautifulSoup` to get the login form, with all the hidden form fields etc.  (The CSRF ones are particularly important, as the server will reject a POST request without the correct values).
- Build your POST data dictionary from the parsed login form data + your username and password
- POST that data to https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit (you might have to fake some of the headers too, as it might only accept requests marked as AJAX)
- Finally GET http://www.linkedin.com/nhome

You can see this whole process by opening the developer tools in chrome/firefox and going through the login process in the network tab.

Something like this should work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get login form
URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login'
session = requests.session()
login_response = session.get('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login')
login = BeautifulSoup(login_response.text)

# Get hidden form inputs
inputs = login.find('form', {'name': 'login'}).findAll('input', {'type': ['hidden', 'submit']})

# Create POST data
post = {input.get('name'): input.get('value') for input in inputs}
post['session_key'] = 'username'
post['session_password'] = 'password'

# Post login
post_response = session.post('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit', data=post)

# Get home page
home_response = session.get('http://www.linkedin.com/nhome')
home = BeautifulSoup(home_response.text)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with python,so the procedure above is so difficult to me,could you try and give me the correct code?