# Fetching information from network projectors using python script

Tags: python, networking, tkinter, projector

I have a small network which includes multiple PCs and projectors. Normally, I am able to see the projector status(running time, lamp life, etc) via browser when i typed in the ip address of particular projector. I am wondering if it is possible to fetch the information of the projectors on the network using a python script. My idea is to create a small tkinter app which will display those projector status when the user request.I must admit that i am being too ambitious as  i don't have enough knowledge on network programming. But if any of you can help me out , i will greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sort of depends on how complicated the page is. If it's plain text, then something like this should work

```
import urllib
stats_text = urllib.urlopen('http://ip.of.projector').read()
```

If you need to parse the returned page at all to extract the values, you might want to look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: It works like a champ! thanks a lot. the only problem i am having now is that when i run the script, it ask me to enter user name and password to access the page. Is there anyway to automate the process?

Comment: If the page is using HTTP Basic Authentication, the solutions in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635113/python-urllib2-basic-http-authentication-and-tr-im) might work for you.

Comment: thanks Adam, it works! i think it's time for me to do some parsing with beautiful soup. Again, thanks a lot for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it several ways, but since you have not given so much information I would recommend going with [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/documentation.html) or [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/), both work as a browser so you can read what's on the HTML and even fill/submit forms and much more.

Comment: thanks for your answer too. the example in mechanize is almost the same as what Adam said. Useful stuffs!