# Get content of protected web pages using Python

Tags: python, authentication, urllib2

How can you get content of protected pages using Python and urllib2?

I need to specify a username and password for the pages that I am trying to retrieve..
e.g.

```
content = urllib2.urlopen(URL, username, password).read()
```

I know that is not part of the urllib2 API.. Just give an example of what I would need, from the API.

Comment: HTML pages are usually protected in on of two ways; using a cookie token or using the HTTP Authentication header. You need to figure out which, then either get that cookie (usually by POSTing the username and password to a specific login form action), or by adding a [Authorization header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635113/python-urllib2-basic-http-authentication-and-tr-im)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look at the [python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/#) library.

It has great support for [basic http authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication.html#basic-authentication) out of the box.

e.g.

```
import requests
content = requests.get(URL, auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Using `requests` you can also set up `sessions` (for cookie management) and easily `POST` data (e.g. a login form) and keep the cookie to browse all the pages only accessible to logged in users.

Read more about [session objects](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced.html#session-objects) and [posting data](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#more-complicated-post-requests) in the excellent documentation.

If you absolutely have to use `urllib2` here's a useful snippet taken from another thread for basic HTTP authentication:

```
import urllib2, base64

request = urllib2.Request("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user")
base64string = base64.standard_b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with urllib2 just look at the [Urllib docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html)

its actually a lot easier to enter into form using a web driver like selenium but the thing about selenium is it opens an actual window while urllib is in the background but selenium is much easier to use

[Selenium API](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html)

those are just some suggestions that i hope helped