# 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials python

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, urllib2

```
import urllib2
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({ "http" : "http:proxyIp1", "https" : "proxyIp2"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
try:
    a = urllib2.urlopen("corporate internal link")#, proxies=proxy)
    b = a.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    error = e.read() # this will be your error message
    print error
```

This gives an error:

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
```

I know that i have to give "username" and "password" but can any1 tell how i can give the credentials in this case??
Thanks

Comment: See this -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/4188709/1171280

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source : http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html Check "Use of Basic HTTP Authentication"

Read about `add_password` method [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#http-password-mgr)

```
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://www.example.com:3128/'})
proxy_auth_handler = urllib2.ProxyBasicAuthHandler()
proxy_auth_handler.add_password('realm', 'host', 'username', 'password')

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, proxy_auth_handler)
# This time, rather than install the OpenerDirector, we use it directly:
opener.open('http://www.example.com/login.html')
```

Comment: thanks a lot..Could u please tell me where do i find this "realm"??

Comment: Normally its your domain name.

Comment: Clarification : for example I have  a link "http://www.abc.def.corp:1234", then in this case realm=? host=? username="My username through which I log on to my system" password= ""My password through which I log on to my system""...Is this true?..

Comment: is there anyway other than hardcoding username and password?