# HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required while downloading a file from HTTPS website and saving it

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, https

Basically i need a program that given a URL, it downloads a file and saves it. I know this should be easy but there are a couple of drawbacks here...

First, it is part of a tool I'm building at work, I have everything else besides that and the URL is HTTPS, the URL is of those you would paste in your browser and you'd get a pop up saying if you want to open or save the file (.txt).

Second, I'm a beginner at this, so if there's info I'm not providing please ask me. :)

I'm using Python 3.3 by the way.

I tried this:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://websitewithfile.com')
txt = response.read()
print(txt)
```

And I get:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: I have same problem....in browser content loaded...and you can see content but in python we first send authorization header ..then we can't see any content and see 401 error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily with the requests library.

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://websitewithfile.com/text.txt',verify=False, auth=('user', 'pass'))
print(response.text)
```

to save the file you would type

```
with open('filename.txt','w') as fout:
   fout.write(response.text):
```

(I would suggest you always set verify=True in the resquests.get() command)

[Here is the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/):

Comment: ok, this gave me: 'requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:550)' any thoughts on how to deal with this?

Comment: wow! i have added "verify=False" on line 2, and i get as output "response [200]", i change my question to: how get the file after that?

Comment: what if it is a Post? it doesn't have the same params

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't the browser also ask you to sign in? Then you need to repeat the request with the added authentication like this:

- [Python urllib2, basic HTTP authentication, and tr.im](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635113/python-urllib2-basic-http-authentication-and-tr-im)
- Equally good: [Python, HTTPS GET with basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999565/python-https-get-with-basic-authentication?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have Requests module, then the code below works for python 2.6 or later. Not sure about 3.x

```
import urllib

testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("https://randomsite.com/file.gz", "/local/path/to/download/file")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution: https://github.qualcomm.com/graphics-infra/urllib-siteminder

```
import siteminder
import getpass
url = 'https://XYZ.dns.com'
r = siteminder.urlopen(url, getpass.getuser(), getpass.getpass(), "dns.com")
Password:<Enter Your Password>

data = r.read() / pd.read_html(r.read())  # need to import panda as pd for the second one
```