# facebook pages scraping need login

Tags: python

I am scraping the facebook pages data, but to access all the data I need to log in to my account I am using.

```
import wget
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.facebook.com/hellomeets/events"

down = wget.download(url)

f = open(down, 'r')
htmlText = "\n".join(f.readlines())
f.close()
print htmlText
```

How do I log in to my account and scrape all the data of pages?

Comment: use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) OR use their facebook api

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, I found that Facebook implements some kind of CRSF protection, thus simple urllib3 or requests wouldn't work.

Try something like this :
[Login to Facebook using python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928368/login-to-facebook-using-python-requests) which still uses requests, but with session

Answer (score 0):

For python3, you could use the [urllib library](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html).

Here's an example of someone using it to log in to a site.

[How to use urllib in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24635064/4293747)