# urllib.request.urlopen(url) with Authentication

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, beautifulsoup, request

I've been playing with beautiful soup and parsing web pages for a few days. I have been using a line of code which has been my saviour in all the scripts that I write. The line of code is :

```
r = requests.get('some_url', auth=('my_username', 'my_password')).
```

BUT ...

I want to do the same thing with (OPEN A URL WITH AUTHENTICATION):

```
(1) sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read() (1)
(2) soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser") (2)
```

I'm not able to open a url and read, the webpage which needs authentication. 
How do I achieve something like this :

```
  (3) sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url, auth=(username, password)).read() (3) 
instead of (1)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have a look at the [HOWTO Fetch Internet Resources Using The urllib Package](https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/urllib2.html#id6) from the official docs:

```
# create a password manager
password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

# Add the username and password.
# If we knew the realm, we could use it instead of None.
top_level_url = "http://example.com/foo/"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, username, password)

handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)

# create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)

# use the opener to fetch a URL
opener.open(a_url)

# Install the opener.
# Now all calls to urllib.request.urlopen use our opener.
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

Comment: Please see the line (2) in the question. I need to parse the sauce using beautiful soup. How do I achieve that using your code?

Comment: `AbstractBasicAuthHandler does not support the following scheme: 'Bearer'`

Comment: @ChristianKönig `Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1014, in http_error_auth_reqed
    raise ValueError("AbstractBasicAuthHandler does not "
ValueError: AbstractBasicAuthHandler does not support the following scheme: 'Digest'`

Answer (score 33):

You're using `HTTP Basic Authentication`:

```
import urllib2, base64

request = urllib2.Request(url)
base64string = base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

So you should `base64` encode the username and password and send it as an `Authorization` header.

Comment: import urllib2 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/python3-error-import-error-no-module-name-urllib2

Comment: for python3 is not working. error: TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648149/4609258 for a working version of this example in python3

Answer (score 6):

With [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) :

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
myHeaders = urllib3.util.make_headers(basic_auth='my_username:my_password')
http.request('GET', 'http://example.org', headers=myHeaders)
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks.  To get the returned data, dump the response into a variable; the data is in variable.data

Comment: important note, urllib3 is not in the standard library (unlike urllib which is)

Answer (score 2):

Use this. This is standard urllib found with Python3 installation. Works great guaranteed. Also, see [gist](https://gist.github.com/kaito834/36e693a3a54057666d28)

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://192.168.0.1/'

auth_user="username"
auth_passwd="^&%$$%^"

passman = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, auth_user, auth_passwd)
authhandler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

res = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
res_body = res.read()
print(res_body.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I got AbstractBasicAuthHandler does not support the following scheme: 'Negotiate'

Comment: ok simple way.. just use Postman and make it work, and use 'code' to get python or curl etc to get the code. copy paste woohoo.

Answer (score 0):

In `python3` using [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) you can use the below code

```py
# Using urllib as this is a built-in tool and there is no need to install any third-party lib
import urllib
import urllib.request

auth = (
    "my_username",
    "my_password",
)

"""
This function needs to be called only once
Once the opener is installed subsequent call will use the same authentication
"""


def install_authenticated_request_opener():
    password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    password_mgr.add_password(None, project_artifactory_url, auth[0], auth[1])

    handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)

    # create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)

    # Install the opener.
    # Now all calls to urllib.request.urlopen use our opener.
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)


def download_html(base_url):
    html_request = urllib.request.Request(some_url)
    try:
        result = urllib.request.urlopen(html_request)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        # handling error as that is important 
        print(
            "Network call failed. Error code:",
            e.code or "no HTTP status code",
            "reason:",
            e.reason or "missing reason",
        )
        # uncomment to raise this exception
        # raise e
    else:
        # Everything is fine
        htmlText = result.read()
        parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(htmlText, "html.parser")
        # Do something with the parsed HTML
```

If you are with the [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library then you can use below code

```py
import requests

auth = (
    "my_username",
    "my_password",
)

def download_html(some_url):
    resp = req.get(some_url, auth=auth)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        print(
            "Network call failed. Error code:",
            resp.status_code or "no HTTP status code",
        )
        # uncomment to raise this exception
        # raise e
    else:
        # Everything is fine
        htmlText = result.read()
        parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(htmlText, "html.parser")
        # Do something with the parsed HTML
```

If you are using `python2` for [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html) solution, you have to go with this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72395558/5028085)

You can also read this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804320/5028085) for the advantage of `requests` lib over `urllib`