# python: urllib download with password

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to download a zip file from a secure website, this is my code:

```
import urllib
username = "us"
password = "pass"

url = "https://ssl.isr.umich.edu/hrs/files2.php?versid=189"
testfile = urllib.FancyURLopener(username,password)
testfile.retrieve(url,"filetest1.pdf")
```

The errors include: syntax error, invalid syntax. Can someone help me out please. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? I get `AssertionError: proxies must be a mapping`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib.request.urlopen(url) with Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239822/urllib-request-urlopenurl-with-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the contents of `/files2.php` you must login using the form in `/login2.php`

```
import urllib2
from urllib import urlencode
from cookielib import CookieJar

username = "us"
password = "pass"
login = 'https://ssl.isr.umich.edu/hrs/login2.php'

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(CookieJar()))
data = {'fuser':username, 'fpass':password, 'submit':'Login'}
opener.open(login, data=urlencode(data))
```

Then you can use `opener` to download the files and write to disk, example:

```
url = 'https://ssl.isr.umich.edu/hrs/filedownload2.php?d=833'
r = opener.open(url)
with open("filetest1.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.read())
```