# How to authenticate ngrok password automatically using Python and or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ngrok

I am using ngrok to expose my localhost on a raspberry pi, and ngrok is password protected. I am using Django on another computer outside my network to access a webpage(simple server) on this raspberry pi. I don't want to manually type in the username and password to ngrok.

How can I automatically fill in the ngrok user/password, which is a popup in chrome asking for user and password?

What I've tried:
I first tried using JS in my template, just using a fetch request:
`https://user:password@myngrokdomain.ngrok.io` but chrome threw an error in the console saying I can't pass in credentials in plain text like this, rightfully so...

I then tried to use python requests:

```
    UN= "myuser"
    PWD = "mypassword"
    loginURL = "https://myngrokdomain.ngrok.io"
    client = requests.session()
    login_data = dict(username=UN, password=PWD,)
    r = client.post(loginURL, data=login_data)
```

This returned a 401 access denied

`r.headers + r.reason` returns:
`401 Unauthorized Unauthorized {'Content-Length': '16', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Www-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="ngrok"', 'Date': 'Tue, 16 Mar 2021 15:22:15 GMT'}`

Comment: maybe this will help you   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506092/python-requests-get-always-get-404/47506205#47506205

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The authentication method used by ngrok is called HTTP Basic Auth. To use it with the requests library you pass login and password as a tuple in the `auth` argument:

```
r = client.post(loginURL, auth=(UN, PWD))
```

Docs: [Basic Authentication — Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)

Comment: Thanks @Igonato. Where did you find, or how did you know, that ngrok used this type of authentication?

Comment: @MattG The `Www-Authenticate` header specifies the authentication method that should be used to gain access to a resource, it says Basic right in it. Also, when you see the native browser popup it's Basic Auth. And passing credentials in a URL like user:pass@example.com - that's also only works for Basic Auth

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a get on the login page first. Perhaps it's setting some cookies that it expects to be present on the post :

```
    UN= "myuser"
    PWD = "mypassword"
    loginURL = "https://myngrokdomain.ngrok.io"
    client = requests.session()
    login_data = dict(username=UN, password=PWD,)
    client.get(loginURL )
    r = client.post(loginURL, data=login_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish whether you're making the request from a browser or from a server application.

### Browser

If you're doing it from a browser you're hitting a CORS issue and ngrok doesn't support that when providing `--auth`. From the [docs](https://ngrok.com/docs#cors-basic-auth):

> you cannot use ngrok's -auth option. ngrok's http tunnels allow you to specify basic authentication credentials to protect your tunnels. However, ngrok enforces this policy on *all* requests, including the preflight OPTIONS requests that are required by the CORS spec. In this case, your application must implement its own basic authentication

In this case, your only option is to implement authentication in your application instead of using ngrok's `--auth`.

### Server

If you're sending the request from a server application you won't get into any CORS issue but you need to provide the Basic Authentication credentials properly.

Say you have your application exposed via ngrok at `http://myapp.ngrok.io` protected via `--auth user:pass`.

In plain Node.js you would do something like this:

```js
const http = require('http')

http.get('http://myapp.ngrok.io', { auth: 'user:pass' }, res => {
  const chunks = []

  res.on('data', chunk => {
    chunks.push(chunk)
  })

  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf-8'))
  })
})
```

Note that to hit the https url you would use Node's `https` module instead of `http`, or a higher level library that handles that for you, like [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

In Python you can do something similar and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239822/urllib-request-urlopenurl-with-authentication) will probably get you on the right path.